# How to deserialize json to class with missing fields

Tags: json, gson, json-deserialization

I'm following a tutorial where one of the tasks is to deserialize json using gson. I looked at several SO posts, but couldn't find one that addressed my issue. I get a string representation of an array in JSON whose fields look like below:

```
photoJsonArray

[{"id": "28857102437",
"owner":"9457266@N02",
"secret":"a5f02e005f",
"server":"857",
"farm":1,
"title":"",
"ispublic":1,
"isfriend":0,
"isfamily":0,
"url_s":"https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/857\/28857102437_a5f02e005f_m.jpg" ...and so on
```

I want to deserialize this list into a list of `GalleryItem` objects, which only includes the `id`,`url_s` and `id` fields from the JSON array.

I tried the following approach to converting the JSON string to a list of Gallery Item objects, but all the fields ended up with a `null` value.

```
 Type photoType = new TypeToken<List<GalleryItem>>(){}.getType();

List<GalleryItem>galleryList = g.fromJson(photoJsonArray.toString(),photoType);
```

I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research I discovered that all the fields from the JSON string need to be declared in the class in order to deserialize the JSON into that class. Seems a bit overkill if all you need to use is a couple fields, but hope this helps.